# Can not remote control server - Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: server, ssh, remote-desktop, remote, 23.10

I have Ubuntu Desktop + gdm3 installed. I am running Ubuntu Server 23.10, and I installed both packages with apt. I have remote desktop enabled, and remote control enabled on my server, yet I can not control it using RDP from another device. When I connect, I can see what is happening on the screen yet not control it.

I have tried using xrdp but that crashes as soon as I log in.

This is also a **fresh install** of Ubuntu, with nothing but ubuntu-desktop and gdm3 installed.

Answer (score 1):

So, Not recommended to enable Remote Desktop (i.e. sharing feature) and xRDP software on the same machine.  They are listening to the same port and this creates conflict...

So,
**Option 1 - You either uninstall or disable xRDP software and use only Sharing feature.**

Then in the Sharing interface, you will need to perform some configuration.. You have to tell the system if you want to have view only or also remote control.   To use this feature, a user needs to be logged on ! If no one is logged on or if session is locked, you will not be able to RDP to the machine.

You can find more information in our blog about this feature at [Ubuntu – Enable Screen Sharing Features through RDP on Ubuntu 22.04](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=18110)

**Option 2 - You disable Sharing feature and install/use xRDP software.**

If you use xRDP software; you have to know that the same user cannot be logged on locally and remotely at the same time..So, if you want to use xRDP, you have to ensure that no one is logged on on the Ubuntu machine.  Then you will be able to perform a remote connection.   With xRDP, you cannot connect to an existing "console" session.

It might be also useful that you read this post in our blog about xRDP. The script provided can ease the installation of xRDP on UBuntu machines (check at [xRDP – Easy install xRDP on Ubuntu 20.04,22.04,23.XX (Script Version 1.4.8)](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=19228)

These additional links are provided as additional information only...

Comment: this should be pinned for everyone (me) installing XRDP to screen share with local users and struggling with configs